# Typesrcript typing {[key: string]: any}

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
validate(formGroup: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any}
```

and I can

```
return {validateLocation: false}
```

or

```
return {'validateLocation': false}
```

`key:string` shoud be `'validateLocation': false`, why both are all working? validateLocation is NOT string, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. That means it must maintain a certain level of compatibility with JavaScript. While you are right in principle to expect key access to be in the form `'validateLocation'` or `"validateLocation"`, it is necessary also to support the `validateLocation` syntax for compatibility. That leads to these results:

```
let validateLocation: string = 'a';

let value1 = {validateLocation: false} //Key will be "validateLocation"
let value2 = {'validateLocation': false} //Key will be "validateLocation"
let value3 = {"validateLocation": false} //Key will be "validateLocation"
let value4 = {[validateLocation]: false} //Key will be "a"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This compatibility makes Typescript less desirable language. Typescript is compatible with JavaScript, and we still need transpile it to JavaScript. Image that C# need to be compatible with IL and then we still need to compile it to IL ....

Comment: @TonyBao: You can reduce the level of compatibility for a stricter typechecking when you turn off "compile on error" and turn on "no implicit any" in the `tsconfig.json`. The JS compatibility is a good thin when you migrate JS projects. And it makes transition from JS easier.

Comment: Thank you and then we are going to the old road of "restrict" mode.

Comment: @TonyBao: You might come from JS, but I come from C#. When I started Js, poor productivity from the lack of explicit typing made me move to TS after a few days and I am not going back.

Answer (score 3):

Keys in JavaScript objects are always strings. The syntax doesn't require you to specify it, but yes, `validateLocation` here becomes a string key in both cases.

You can see this with:

```
var x = { a: 1 };
console.log(x['a']); // Prints 1, because 'a' the string is a valid key.
```

MDN has more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals.

> Object property names can be any string, including the empty string. If the property name would not be a valid JavaScript identifier or number, it must be enclosed in quotes. Property names that are not valid identifiers also cannot be accessed as a dot (.) property, but can be accessed and set with the array-like notation("[]").

Comment: Thank you Tim. But my code is Typescript code. I thought Typescript is Typing JavaScript to remove these two ways both working issues. Surprised to find the Typing language with these loosed syntax.

Comment: Still true. TypeScript does add types (and more), but the resulting code is just plain JavaScript once it's running (so eventually keys _must_ become strings), and TypeScript types have to reflect reality to work effectively, so they have to treat them as strings. They could have done that by only allowing the string syntax when defining objects, you're right, which would make this clearer. They've chosen to stay on the side of JS consistency there though - that's a choice, rather than necessity.